How to achieve percentage padding/margin in .Net MAUI?
I am looking for a way to achieve padding or margin by percentage in .NET MAUI. In CSS, this can be done easily using a rule like padding: 0 5%;. Is there a similar approach or best practice in .NET MAUI for setting padding or margin based on percentages?"

The direct answer to the question is "NO". You can "hack" it with Grid. You can do calculations at runtime and change it. None of this will be simple and without side effects.

Btw, if you decide to go with the Grid, and you have something like Image, remember to set the Margin to negative ( -2 ) on the image, otherwise you will have problems with the outside most pixel of the image. (Yes, it is that bad.)

Yes, looks like using Grid with different * as the width definitions would be the most direct and a simple solution.

You can also use CommunityToolkit.Maui's MathExpressionConverter. HeightRequest="{Binding Parent.Height, Source={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MathExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter='x*9/10'}"

Using Grid or StackLayout with Dynamic Sizing
You can use a Grid or StackLayout  or FlexLayout to create responsive designs. Here’s how you can manage padding and margins:
Example with Grid
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             x:Class="YourNamespace.MainPage">

    <Grid Padding="5%" Margin="5%">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Header"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Text="Main Content"
               Grid.Row="1"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

Using OnSizeAllocated for Dynamic Padding/Margin
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        
        // Calculate 5% padding
        double padding = width * 0.05;

        // Apply the padding to a ContentView or any other layout
        myContentView.Padding = new Thickness(padding);
        myContentView.Margin = new Thickness(padding);
    }
}

